# Finding the difference in time between two events for a specific ID

Tags: python, pandas

Details about code:

- Dataframe (x) shape: (20494463, 31)
- In this Dataframe, each id shows up multiple times with different events and the event dates. What I'm looking for is the time between the first time event `A` occurs and the first time event `B` occurs for each `id`
- `feature_final.index.values` is another Dataframe whose indexes are the id's I need to work with

```
def feature(x):
   times = []
   for j in feature_final.index.values:

     pat = x[x.id == j]
     min_dates_j = pat.groupby(["event_description"]).min()

     try:
         time = ((min_dates_j.loc["A","event_description"] -  min_dates_j.loc["B","event_description"]).days) 
     except:
         #RX or DX not present
         time = np.NaN()

     times.append(time)

     return times
```

Comment: Are you sure that the code is correctly posted? The `times` result will never contain more than one value.

Comment: How about adding some sample data? It will make writing some feedback much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Some general suggestions:

- Run the code through `pycodestyle` to get several suggestions for writing idiomatic Python:

  - > indentation is not a multiple of four
  - > missing whitespace after ','
  - > multiple spaces after operator
  - > line too long
  - > do not use bare except' [sic]
  - > block comment should start with '# '
- Don't use single letter variables - it makes it very hard to maintain the code.
- Don't shadow common names like `time` - if you ever need the `time` module in the code you'll have to rename the import or your variable.
- You have unnecessary outer parens in the `time = …` line.
- Indexing by a non-trivial expression is confusing. Assign `x.id == j` to a variable first so the maintainer knows what it means.
- `feature_final` is accessed like a global. You should instead pass it in.
- If you're processing a huge list you might want to try returning an iterable instead of a list - that way other code can start processing the output before it's complete.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Do you have any feedback on how to improve its performance?